# Configure Mail Server to receive mail from any domain

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have a postfix mail server on ubuntu on my virtualbox,now the domain of the mail server is abc.com...hence it receives mail from any "from address" but the "to address" needs to be proper i.e a valid user in the mailserver.

Now,in my project i am sending fake mails to user whose mail id consists of other domains too...like cde.com

My final objective is to show the mails in the mail server.

When i tried that ,it goes directly in to the mailserveer logs i.e /var/log/mail.log i.e as an error

is there any way i can store these mails in the mailserver??

Answer (score 3):

add cde.com to mydestination

```
# sed -ie 's/mydestination =/mydestination = cde.com,/' /etc/postfix/main.cf
# postfix reload
postfix/postfix-script: refreshing the Postfix mail system
# postconf | grep "^mydestination"
mydestination = cde.com, abc.com
```